# Understanding sort() compareFunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with an ecommerce platform that lacks the ability to reorder the options of our product attribute fields. It really sucks because to insert a new option you pretty much have to delete all of the existing ones and start over. I'm trying to do it client-side instead. Here's what I'm working with (this one's for a shoe size):

- 9 EE
- 9 1/2 EE
- 10 EE
- 10 1/2 EE
- 11 EE
- 11 1/2 EE
- 9 EEEE
- 9 1/2 D
- 9 1/2 EEEE
- 10 EEEE
- 10 1/2 EEEE
- 11 EEEE
- 9 D
- 11 1/2 EEEE

These are actually the text of some `<option>`s in a form. The format of the values is `X Y Z` where:

- `X` is a whole number
- `Y` is the string "1/2" and may not be present
- `Z` is a letter code which is either "D", "E", "EEE", or "EEEE", and may not be present

The desired order of the above would be this:

- 9 D
- 9 1/2 D
- 9 EE
- 9 1/2 EE
- 9 EEEE
- 9 1/2 EEEE
- 10 EE
- 10 1/2 EE
- 10 EEEE
- 10 1/2 EEEE
- 11 EE
- 11 1/2 EE
- 11 EEEE
- 11 1/2 EEEE

I've learned a little bit about javascript's `sort()` function but haven't been able to fully comprehend how the comparison function that you can pass to it works. I've got this so far:

```
<select>
    <option>9 EE</option>
    <option>9 1/2 EE</option>
    <option>10 EE</option>
    <option>10 1/2 EE</option>
    <option>11 EE</option>
    <option>11 1/2 EE</option>
    <option>9 EEEE</option>
    <option>9 1/2 D</option>
    <option>9 1/2 EEEE</option>
    <option>10 EEEE</option>
    <option>10 1/2 EEEE</option>
    <option>11 EEEE</option>
    <option>9 D</option>
    <option>11 1/2 EEEE</option>
</select>
```

I started with the code taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/667198/398242

```
$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}));
```

Which sorts the items like this (doesn't work for even the first criteria):

- 10 1/2 EE
- 10 1/2 EEEE
- 10 EE
- 10 EEEE
- 11 1/2 EE
- 11 1/2 EEEE
- 11 EE
- 11 EEEE
- 9 1/2 D
- 9 1/2 EE
- 9 1/2 EEEE
- 9 D
- 9 EE
- 9 EEEE

I see that in javascript `'11' > '9'` returns `false`, which in no way makes sense to me.

[MDN describes the compare function argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as such, and I kind of get it:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

...but I haven't got a clue how to adapt this to fit my requirements. I've tried a few things but I just feel like I'm shooting in the dark. I've tried to show that I've taken some time to attempt an understanding of this problem. I'm interested in learning more, but for now I'd just like to get this issue solved.

http://jsfiddle.net/DnwJ6/ Any clues?

Comment: I think here the solution is to somehow normalize both `a` and `b` to a format like `\d\d (1/2|0/0) [a-z]*` before comparing them

Comment: `"11" > "9" === false` makes perfect sense. You're comparing **strings**. Try converting to numbers first

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZnLJh/

Comment: @Ian I get that they're strings, but 11 is a longer string than 9, numeric values being irrelevant. Is it because it's only looking at the first character? What's going on, what is being compared? I don't see how to convert these values to numbers.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Comparing strings and string length are two different things. Take for example the words "bat" and "apricot". If you compare string lengths then "bat" should come before "apricot" in the dictionary. It doesn't does it? How do you compare it? Think about it.

Comment: @slebetman So the "numbers" are being sorted "alphabetically" so to speak? That was my guess... is that correct? `111, 22, 3333, 334` etc.?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That's what comparing "strings" mean. A string is a series of "alphabets" (technically called characters since numbers, symbols and spaces are technically not part of the english alphabet). A computer treats it as such and does not know any better unless you write your own algorithm to interpret the string differently. Also, technically it doesn't really compare by alphabet, it compares by the character's position/number in UTF8/ASCII. For example 'A' comes before 'a' and '?' comes before 'A' but '_' comes before 'a' and after 'A'.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, I understand it perfectly now.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I believe it's called lexicographical sorting, which basically means "alphabetic" sorting. Here's a source from the ES5 spec: http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5 - and if you scroll down just a little bit, you can look at #4, but you'll see **Note 2**, which explains comparing strings in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one out:

```
$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
    var regex = /(\d+)((?: 1\/2)? )([DE]+)/;
    var abreakdown = a.text.match(regex), bbreakdown = b.text.match(regex);
    if (parseInt(abreakdown[1]) === parseInt(bbreakdown[1])) {
        if (abreakdown[3] === bbreakdown[3]) {
            return (abreakdown[2] === bbreakdown[2] ? 0 : (abreakdown[2] < bbreakdown[2] ? -1 : 1));    
        } else {
            return abreakdown[3] < bbreakdown[3] ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } else { return parseInt(abreakdown[1]) - parseInt(bbreakdown[1]); }
}));
```

It uses a regex to break the pieces down and then do comparison based on each component.

[**Demo fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/DnwJ6/1/)

Comment: Great. Hope it was of help. Btw, `'11' > '9' ` returns `false` because it is a string comparison. You see, I used `parseInt()` on the strings before comparing them to use their number values instead.

Comment: Couple issues when the string doesn't match the pattern at all (undefined index errors), so I'll have to plug in some defense before I can use this globally. Will test tomorrow, I'm exhausted - thx again.

Comment: Let me know what are those patterns. We can make the regex more flexible. Come by tomorrow and we'll adapt where needed.

Comment: I'm using "Miva Merchant" which is notorious for third party developers selling you addons to achieve basic functionality, so it didn't take too long before I decided the sort feature didn't exist. I finally found it after a couple days `facepalm.gif` so I don't need this any more, but I truly appreciate all the answers. Definitely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Put the values in an array in the order you want them:

```
var shoeSizes = [ '9 D','9 1/2 D','9 EE','9 1/2 EE', ...]
```

Use *Array.protoype.indexOf* ([with a shim for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)) to get the index of the matched text in the array. Use the index for the value to compare, something like:

```
function(a,b) {
  return shoeSizes.indexOf(a) - shoeSizes.indexOf(b);
}
```

If you need to deal with values that aren't in the array, test the value returned by *indexOf* and substitute a default if it's -1.

Alternatively you can make the sizes the names of property values in an object and assign a specific value:

```
var shoeSizes = { '9 D': 5, '9 1/2 D': 10, '9 EE': 15, '9 1/2 EE': 20, ...};
```

Then use the value  in the compare:

```
function(a,b) {
  return shoeSizes[a] - shoeSizes[b];
}
```

Or to allow for default values:

```
function(a,b) {
  return (a in shoeSizes? shoeSizes[a] : 1000) - (b in shoeSizes? shoeSizes[b] : 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm working with existing HTML, so I'll have to chew on this a bit before I can apply it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I definitely can't use either of these options. The customer provides the values, I just want to blindly look at strings. I'm not sure how *"Put the values in an array in the order you want them"* is useful here, if I could do that my problem would already be solved. I don't know what the values are, just the format. Thanks though.

Comment: If you don't know what the values are, how do you know how to sort them? You seem to want to sort some things without knowing how to sort them beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have formatted text, one way is to normalize the text elements before comparing them.

This solution may not be that optimal, but will do the job

```
$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return nomalize(a.text) < nomalize(b.text) ? -1 : 1;
}));

function nomalize(val){
    var parts =  val.split(' '), op = '';

    op = parts[0].length == 1 ? '0' + parts[0] : parts[0];
    if(parts.length > 1){
        if(/[a-z]/i.test(parts[1])){
            op += '0/0' + parts[1];
        } else {
            op += parts[1]
        }
    }

    op += parts.length > 2 ? parts[2] : '';
    return op;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZnLJh/)

**If somebody can suggest any solution to optimize it further it will be great**

Comment: It doesn't quite match the desired output (look at the 1/2 sizes), but this will certainly do for now. I'll have to think about this more later on so I can understand it, for now I just need some code to slam into the website so I can go to bed. Thanks.

Comment: @WesleyMurch a little better one can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZnLJh/4/

Comment: I'm trying to match the desired output in the post. All of these solutions are better than what I have, so I'll use this for now, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to understand is that `12` is *indeed* less than `9` if you're sorting the *textual* items rather than the numbers. That's because `<1>` `<2>` is less than `<9>` `<nothing>` because `1` and `9` are the "primary keys" in that case.

The second problem you face is whether the length (9 1/2) is the primary key or the width (EE) is. I would suspect the former would make more sense so proceed on that basis.

Having decided that, your best bet is to provide a sort function for the call, one which turns each string into a numeric value and then compares that value. For example:

1. Get the first (space-delimited) field (9) and set your value to that.
2. If the next field exists and is `1/2`, add `0.5` to that value.
3. If the last field exists (the alpha one), simply convert that to some value less than `0.5` and add it (eg, `a` -> 0.01, `B` -> 0.02, ..., `EEEE` -> 0.08 and so on).

That last one depends on the relative ordering of widths, I've chosen a typical American system.

What you end up with there is a value which dictates the proper ordering and your sort function can then simply do a numeric comparison. An example follows:

```
function xlat(s) {
    var s2 = s.split(" ");

    var n = parseInt(s2[0]);
    if (s2.length == 1) { return n; }

    var last = s2[1];
    if (last == '1/2') {
        n = n + 0.5;
        if (s2.length == 2) { return n; }
        last = s2[2];
    }
    var widths = ['A','B','C','D','E','EE','EEE','EEEE','F','G'];
    n = n + widths.indexOf(last) / 100;
    return n;
}

$("select").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
    var na = xlat(a.text);
    var nb = xlat(b.text);
    return na == nb ? 0 : na < nb ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

The `xlat` functions is the important one here. It first splits the size into an array of 1, 2 or 3 elements and gets the numeric value for the first. If the second and third aren't there, this value gets returned (handles "naked" sizes like `9` or `13`).

Otherwise it decides whether it's a half-increment length - this is decided if the second field is `1/2`. At this point, it also detects if there is no width and returns the size.

Once past this point, we have the size (either whole or half) and the `last` variable holds the width. We then simply add a value based on this size's position within an array, suitably modified (divided by 100) so that it doesn't affect the major key.

By using that code with your own, you get (as expected):

```
9 D
9 EE
9 EEEE
9 1/2 D
9 1/2 EE
9 1/2 EEEE
10 EE
10 EEEE
10 1/2 EE
10 1/2 EEEE
11 EE
11 EEEE
11 1/2 EE
11 1/2 EEEE
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define a proper sort key with which you can make sane comparisons; the following function uses a regular expression to dig out the useful bits of information:

```
function sortkey(val)
{
    var matches = val.match(/^(\d+)( 1\/2)? (\w+)$/),
    number = +matches[1];

    if (matches[2]) {
      number += 0.5; // add "1/2"
    }

    return [number, matches[3]];
}
```

The first match is cast into a number; if the second match is available, `0.5` is added. Afterwards, the last match is added as the secondary sort key. The return value is something like this:

```
[9.5, 'EE']
```

This structure can then be used for your comparison function:

```
function compareFunc(a, b) {
    var sa = sortkey(a.text),
    sb = sortkey(b.text);

    if (sa[0] == sb[0]) {
        return sa[1] < sb[1] ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return sa[0] < sb[0] ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Applied to your specific code:

```
var $sorted = $('select > option').sort(compareFunc);
$('select').html($sorted);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/urakas/2/)

Comment: Upvotes all around, I won't be able to really let all this info sink in for long term understanding tonight, will have to read through tomorrow. For the moment, accepting the answer that spoon-fed me exactly what I needed.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Fair enough; the advantage of this particular approach is that the logic of building the sort key is decoupled from the actual sorting process, making both parts simpler to adapt :)

Comment: @WesleyMurch Looking at the code again, I realized I made a mistake; comparisons of arrays forces a string based comparison :( updated the code to still make use of the sorting key generator function.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already have a working solution, but just for comparison (pun intended), here is one of the many other ways to do it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/ZkaaE/)):

```
// Make a shoe size sortable as text
function sortableSize( text ) {
    // Split the size into parts separated by spaces
    var parts = text.split( ' ' );
    // The first part is the size number;
    // make sure it is two digits (09,10,etc.)
    if( parts[0].length == 1 )
        parts[0] = '0' + parts[0];
    // If it wasn't a 1/2 size, make it 0/2
    if( parts.length == 2 )
        parts.splice( 1, 0, '0/2' );
    // So '9 EE' becomes '09 0/2 EE'
    return parts.join( ' ' );
}

var $options = $('#sizes option');
$options = $options.sort( function( a, b ) {
    a = sortableSize( a.text );
    b = sortableSize( b.text );
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
});
$('#sizes').html( $options );
```

This method creates a text representation of each shoe size that is directly sortable as text. Then it sorts using those text representations.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get how to do this now in general. As it turns out, there's more work/testing I have to do on this to get it to work globally across every product in the store, so I may end up switching the accepted answer anyways, I just didn't want people to spend too much time on my rather narrow problem while I had a "good enough" answer, but the answers have certainly helped me understand for next time.