# What is the logic behind the sort method used with a compareFunction?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying the sort() method with a comapreFunction and I do not understand how the compareNumbers() works. Used with the two variables it returns -3, but when used on an array with the sort method it returns a sorted array. Why does it work like this?

```
var things = ['Elvis',555,'R2D2'];

function compareNumbers(a, b){
  return a-b;
}
var a = 5;
var b = 8;

console.log(compareNumbers(a,b)); //returns -3
console.log(compareNumbers(things));//returns NaN
console.log(things.sort(compareNumbers(a,b)));//returns a sorted array
```

What is the logic behind the sort method used with the compareFunction so that it returns a sorted array?
Why doesn't it return NaN?

Where can I check what is the code behind a method like library or documentation?

I saw this [Understanding sort() compareFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562100/understanding-sort-comparefunction) but it is just overwhelming for me at this stage.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476. It's for PHP, but the principles are the same and only the implementation syntax differs a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *calling* `compareNumbers` and passing its return value into `sort`, which isn't what you want. You want to pass the *function* into `sort`, so `sort` calls it:

```
console.log(things.sort(compareNumbers));
// No (), no a and b -----------------^
```

**But** it's important to note that when either `a` or `b` is `"Elvis"` or `"R2D2"`, your comparator function (`compareNumbers`) returns `NaN`, meaning that it's not a "consistent comparison function" according to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). This means that whatever `sort` does at that point is "implementation defined" — totally up to the JavaScript engine's authors, not covered by the specification at all, and likely to vary from one engine to another. `sort` expects to see a negative number, `0`, or a positive number, not `NaN`. Your `things` array shouldn't be sorted numerically at all, as two of its entries are not numbers nor can they be correctly converted to numbers.

Here's an example of using a comparator function correctly: In this case, it takes your array and sorts them according to the length of each entry converted to a string:

```js
var things = ['Elvis',555,'R2D2'];

function compareLengths(a, b){
  return String(a).length - String(b).length;
}

snippet.log(things.sort(compareLengths));
```

```html
<!-- Temporary snippet object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`compareNumbers(a,b)` returns `-3` so you are calling `things.sort(-3)`. Since `-3` isn't a function it is ignored and the default sort algorithm is used.

Comment: From the specification it seems to me `sort` should throw a `TypeError` when passed -3 instead of a function as argument. But (in Chrome anyway) it doesn't. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

Comment: @Stuart — "If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined."

Comment: It also says "If IsCallable(comparefn) is false, throw a TypeError exception."