# Sort drop down options

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667198/1016900) to sort out a drop down menu but having two digits in the options, 14 and 11 comes before 8 and 9.

How should I approach this?

My code is as follows:

```
<select id="test">
    <option>Size 9</option>
    <option>Size 14</option>
    <option>Size 8</option>
    <option>Size 11</option>
</select>

$("#test").html($("#test option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
}))
```

I will need a solution to sort the drop down even if there are only characters, not mixed.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d39W7/)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "only characters"? Do you mean something like "small", "medium" and "large"?

Comment: You are comparing strings. `Size 14` is always in first place before `Size 9`. Put numerical values for options so you can sort by numbers.

Comment: you want sort strings or number

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Actually you are sorting as per text.So when sorting applies it first sort w.r.t to first digit in that case 1 come before 8,9 and then it sort afterwards.

Comment: both strings and numbers; so yes, I would sometimes have small, medium and large

Comment: also, I can't change the format from 'Size 15' to just 15

Comment: Have you considered giving your options values?

Comment: I haven't to be honest, I don't think I would be able to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use following snippet which btw will set value for each option:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4eC/)

```
$("#test").html($("#test option").val(function(){
    return this.text.match(/\d+/);
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var a = parseInt(a.value,10), b = parseInt(b.value,10);
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

Or without setting values:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4eC/1/)

```
$("#test").html($("#test option").sort(function (a, b) {
    var a = parseInt(a.text.match(/\d+/),10), b = parseInt(b.text.match(/\d+/),10);
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

**EDIT:** ( following comment)

You could skip sorting default option like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4eC/2/)

```
$("#test").html($("#test option").val(function (i) {
    return i !== 0 ? this.text.match(/\d+/) : this.value;
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    var a = parseInt(a.value !== ""?a.value:-1, 10),
        b = parseInt(b.value, 10);
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

Comment: thanks; how would I make it ignore the first option with '<option class="" value="">-- Choose a size --</option>'? As that is getting sorted too.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by value

html

```
<select id="test">
    <option value='9'>Size 9</option>
    <option value='14'>Size 14</option>
    <option value='8'>Size 8</option>
    <option value='11'>Size 11</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$("#test").html($("#test option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).val()) == parseInt($(b).val()) ? 0 : parseInt($(a).val()) < parseInt($(b).val()) ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d39W7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

When you compare text two text field, that contains some numbers. **Comparison works on first numeric value only.**

For example : *if we compare size 9 with size 14, then you can get surprising results like size 9 is greater than size 14. This is because only first numeric value is being compare so for 14 the value is numeric value is 1.*

In your case a simple solution might be applying a value field to options and using value for comparisons.

```
<select id="test">
    <option value ="9">Size 9</option>
    <option value ="14">Size 14</option>
    <option value ="8">Size 8</option>
    <option value ="11">Size 11</option>
</select>

$("#test").html($("#test option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.value,10) == parseInt(b.value,10) ? 0 : parseInt(a.value,10) < parseInt(b.value,10) ? -1 : 1;
}))
```