# Loop through dropdowns with a class to set index to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a group of DropDownLists with a class of recur and I want to set their index conditionally in a function like this but it isn't working.
I'm sure there must be a way of doing this?

```
        function DisableFields(disable) {
          if (disable) {
              $('.recur').prop('disabled', true);
              $('.recur').each(function (index, obj) {
                  obj.index(0);
              });
          } else {
              $('.recur').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        }
```

Comment: What isn't working? What's happening instead? What did you expect? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @caTS there is no error but the value of obj is [object HTMLSelectElement] so I'm not sure if I expected to see that or not

Comment: What do you mean by 'set index to 0'? Do you mean set the first option in the list as selected - ie. reset to default state?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Is this `.recur` an `<option>` element within a `<select>`?

Like this?

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option class="recur" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="recur" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="recur" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option class="recur" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Why do you need to change the index? are you attempting to re-order items in this dropdown list?

Your code is currently setting an `index` attribute to 0 for every element. I assume that's not what you're trying to achieve

I'd recommenced making a function for "reordering" them if that's what you intend to do. Rather than doing a multiple things at once in one function.

If you are trying to sort this alphabetically, another stack overflow answer linked here has you covered with the use of jQuery

https://stackoverflow.com/a/667198/20053031

```js
const SortDropdownList = () => {
  $("#cars").html($("option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
  }))
}
```

If you are intending to set the first element as selected, just do the following:

```js
$('#cars option').first().attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: `.recur` is the select, not the option elements. OP is asking how to set the first option as selected, not to sort them.

Comment: The comments regarding the context of this did not exist before my answer was created

Comment: Yep, that's why I commented here to let you know :)

Comment: Up vote because this is a good answer based on the (lack) of information in the question. In fact, the question was very misleading because of the use of jQuery .index().

Answer (score 1):

Aha! This works:

```
obj.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments under your question it appears that your goal is to set the first `option` within each `select` as the chosen value.

To do this you can select the options using `:nth-child(1)` and set the selected property on them:

```js
function DisableFields(disable) {
  $('.recur').prop('disabled', disable);
  disable && $('.recur option:nth-child(1)').prop('selected', true);
}

$('button').on('click', () => DisableFields(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="recur">
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
  <option>Fizz</option>
  <option>Buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="recur">
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
  <option>Fizz</option>
  <option>Buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="recur">
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
  <option>Fizz</option>
  <option>Buzz</option>
</select>
<button>Disable</button>
```

Alternatively, assuming the first option has a `value=""` attribute, as is common practice, you can just set that value on all `select` elements:

```
$('.recur').val('');
```

Comment: up voted, but do you think this is better than OP's own solution using selectIndex?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan No there isn't a value="" attribute, sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: @Yogi 'better' is entirely subjective. My version is a one-liner. The OP's property access is more concise. My version consistently uses jQuery methods, the OPs mixes native and framework. At the end of the day both work, and so long as you and your dev team can understand it, it's good code.