# Place selected item from drop down list in to a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get a selected item from a drop down list, on button click need to show that selected item into a text box.

I haven't tried anything cause i don't know what to do.

Comment: StackOverflow returned *404 Code Not Found*!

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code...

Suppose, Button click event:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Textbox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: thanks this worked, but i didnt need the 'Conver.toString' at the start however when i try add another item from the list it deletes the last item i selected and when they add they are are not at the top of the text box they are in the middle. would you be able to help with this?

Comment: when you try to bind drop down list from database ...make sure that your drop down selected item have order by clause.....if your problem is not solved ...try send your code with proper way...so i can easily find out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222572/sorting-a-dropdownlist-c-asp-net        refet this stackoverflow Link.....for sorting your drop down list

Answer (score 0):

The following class can give you the general idea of doing what you want.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() 
    {
        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        button = new Button();
        textBox = new TextBox();
        button.Click += OnButtonClick;
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    ComboBox comboBox;
    Button button;
    TextBox textBox;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will help without reviewing his/her tried code!